# Creating a memory efficient neural network

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm creating a neural network on python, my problem is a really simple classification problem, I'm using a Leaky ReLu network, that its main goal is to over-fit to a set data points. Before I was working with small data points, my network was really fast if I gave it all the data at once. Now ever now my computer is not able to take it all at once. So I have decided to feed it mini batches of the whole data set, and now it works. Now I have several questions:

1. If I used a loss function before, should I use the same one? (in my case I'm using `BCEWithLogitsLoss`). I ask this because I get really weird loss values in each batch. For example before I made this batches change the loss function goes from being really small, like 0.005 in the model without batches. To being really big.
2. My input data points size `310000 x 3` more or less. Is mini batches the correct approach? Or is there another trick to tackle this problem.
3. Now that I have trained the data, do I have evaluate the trained model in the same way(i.e by batches so I don't run out memory on my GPU)?

Here is my code :

```py
class CustomDataset(Dataset):
   def __init__(self, x_tensor, y_tensor):
       self.x = x_tensor
       self.y = y_tensor
   def __getitem__(self, index):
       return (self.x[index], self.y[index])
   def __len__(self):
       return len(self.x)

class LabelData(Dataset):
   def __init__(self, y_tensor):
       self.y = y_tensor
   def __getitem__(self, index):
       return (self.y[index])
   def __len__(self):
       return len(self.y)

#X, order = common.loadplanes()
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
Samples, Ocupancy = common.load_samples()
x_test = torch.from_numpy(Samples.astype(np.float32)).to(device)
y_test = torch.from_numpy(Ocupancy.astype(np.float32)).to(device)
train_data = CustomDataset(x_test, y_test)
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=train_data, batch_size= 1000, shuffle=False) # Make bigger batches
phi = common.MLP(3, 1).to(device)
criterion = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(phi.parameters(), lr = 0.01)
epoch = 512
fit_start_time = time.time()
for epoch in range(epoch):
   for x_batch, y_batch in train_loader:
       optimizer.zero_grad()
       x_batch = x_batch.to(device)
       y_batch = y_batch.to(device)
       y_pred = phi(x_batch)
       # Compute Loss
       loss = criterion(y_pred.squeeze(), y_batch.squeeze())
       print('Epoch {}: train loss: {}'.format(epoch, loss.item()))    # Backward pass
   loss.backward()
   optimizer.step()

fit_end_time = time.time()
print("Total time = %f" % (fit_end_time - fit_start_time))
X,Y,Z  = np.mgrid[-3000:300:80,-3000:3000:80,-3000:3000:80]
xyz = torch.from_numpy(np.vstack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel(),Z.ravel()]).transpose().astype(np.float32))
# feed the network bit by bit?
xyz = LabelData(xyz)
labels = phi(xyz).to(device)
visualization_iso(X,Y,Z,labels)
```

I'm still running my code as I write this, but I can imagine that the there is going to be an error after the model is trained, that is going to say that I've run out of memory(that is why I'm asking the 3rd question) or that I'm evaluating my network incorrectly, edit it seems I'm evaluating the model wrongly, you can see my error below. Please let me know if I'm not using any common practices or if you spot any mayor flaws on my code.

[image]

Comment: You are doing `loss.backward()` and `optimizer.step()` only once per epoch. You should do it for every mini-batch i.e. it should be inside the inner `for` loop.

Comment: Oh yeah! you are right that is big mistake on my part. Thank you

Comment: Did this correction solve your problem?

Comment: No is bigger than that. I have to edit the code that I gave tho I've changed some stuff.